# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference. How can I resolve this?

Tags: android, weather

I am currently working on an Android studio app. 
I added a button that opens a dialog in which I need to display the weather of the users city. Right now I am having a lot of trouble doing this. For example, an error like this has appeared and I know this question has already been answerd but I still have alot of issues with it.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Apart from this, do I need to do something else to make it work?

This is the code I have:

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
LatLng myPosition;

TextView climaText;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    climaText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.climaText);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);


   /* locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    //locationRequest.setInterval(7500);
    //locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);*/


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Location locationActual = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);;
    if(locationActual != null) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = locationActual.getLatitude();
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = locationActual.getLongitude();
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 16));
        }
    }


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("TESTTAG", "onLocationChanged called");
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 16));
}



@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

private class CityAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1){

                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            String mensaje = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            String wetherInfo = jsonObject.getString("wether");

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(wetherInfo);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String main = jsonObject.getString("main");
                    String description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                    if (main != "" && description != "") {
                        mensaje += main + " " + description + "\n\r";

                    }
                }
            if(mensaje != ""){
                climaText.setText(mensaje);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public void obtenerClima(){

    CityAsyncTask task = new CityAsyncTask();
    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk");

}

public void startDialogReporte(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_reporte,null);
    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

public void starDialogClima(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(dialog_clima,null);
    obtenerClima();
    mBuilder.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

}

Manifest in case you need it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.naluapp.naluapp">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my dialog for the weather only has a text view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON result, "weather" is an array like this :

```
  "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ]
```

so you need to get the weather array like so :

```
JSONArray weatherArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
```

Then loop through weatherArr

Comment: For some reason the problem keeps appearing